# How can I execute "su" on Android?

Tags: android, root, su

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes(command + "\n");
os.writeBytes("exit\n");
os.flush();
process.waitFor();
```

The system says:`"07-06 11:01:34.337: I/System.out(3864): su: uid 10170 not allowed to su"`

I execute "adb root" in my terminal

```
:~/android/android-sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb root

adbd is already running as root
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your adb is running as root, but you only have the stock 'su' tool.  You could use adb to replace it with a customized one of your choice.

Either that, or you do have a customized one and it's been configured not to allow this application userid you are running under - in that case, you need to open its configuration tool and change this.

**Please note** - this is an *old* answer to an *old* question - it's been several Android versions since a conventional `su` stopped being possible on typical end-user Android builds due to the SELinux adoption.  Workarounds are far beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I'm sorry.I'm not good at English.What does "stock 'su' tool" mean?And how can I get a customized one?

Comment: @JoxTraex if adb is running as root as the posted message indicates, the phone is rooted (ie, the user can run arbitrary code as root).  What remains is simply a question of configuring it as desired.

Comment: @android_test - you are going to have to decide for yourself what, if indeed any, unofficial tool you want to trust.  Part of that consideration would be why you need root.

Comment: @Chris Stratton just a test.so, unofficial tool is ok.But I still confused that why I can't execute 'su' now?Why do I have to need and other tools?

Comment: Because the su tool on some android official versions was not meant to be usable by  3rd party developers or end users.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm faced with the same problem. How can I go about replacing the stock su binary with ADB? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/174697/how-to-full-root-a-stock-root-only-android-device

Answer (score 0):

If you are being denied root by the system, there is not much you can do aside from rooting the device.

Comment: True if it were the case, but as they already have root access via adb, this is not relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try [How to get root access and execute](http://muzikant-android.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html).