# How to delete root app/app/ files?

Tags: android, file, root, file-handling

My phone is rooted. I'm trying to do a very simple program. The program should delete file from app/app folder. How can I do this? I'm newbie, so example code is valued.

Answer (score 3):

If your phone is rooted, you can issue commands as root through `su`—provided that the `su` binary is present and in your `PATH`—since Android is a variant of Linux. Simply execute the delete commands through `Runtime.exec()`, and Superuser should take care of the permission prompt.

Here's a simple example of its usage I took [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355480/how-can-i-execute-su-on-android):

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes(command + "\n");
os.writeBytes("exit\n");
os.flush();
process.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete all files inside a folder recursively using the below method.

```
private void DeleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
        {
            child.delete();
            DeleteRecursive(child);
        }

    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```

Comment: Even in a rooted phone? I thought once your phone is rooted, you can do whatever you like.

Comment: This won't work for system directories, because your app is sandboxed and isn't allowed access to it.

Answer (score 1):

On his [github](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser/tree/master/libsuperuser/src/eu/chainfire/libsuperuser), Chainfire provides a [sample implementation](https://github.com/Chainfire/libsuperuser/blob/master/libsuperuser/src/eu/chainfire/libsuperuser/Shell.java) of a `Shell` class that you can use to execute the `rm` command as root. The `rm` command is the Linux variant of the command to delete files (and folders).

**Code Snippet:**

```
if(Shell.SU.available()){
   Shell.SU.run("rm /data/app/app.folder.here/fileToDelete.xml"); //Delete command
else{
   System.out.println("su not found");
```

Or if you are **certain** that the `su` binary is available, you can just run the delete command (commented line) and skip the check

Source: [How-To SU](http://su.chainfire.eu/#how)